# Why am I getting an error when querying SSM parameters via get-parameters-by-path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am trying to query some SSM parameters by path (within Gitbash):

```
aws --region eu-west-2 --profile some-profile ssm get-parameters-by-path --path /prefix/prefix2
```

There are a number of parameters that exist which match this prefix, e.g.

```
/prefix/prefix2/p1
/prefix/prefix2/p2
...
```

I am getting the following error back:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
> GetParametersByPath operation: The parameter doesn't meet the
> parameter name requirements. The parameter name must begin with a
> forward slash "/". It can't be prefixed with "aws" or "ssm"
> (case-insensitive). It must use only letters, numbers, or the
> following symbols: . (period), - (hyphen), _ (underscore). Special
> characters are not allowed. All sub-paths, if specified, must use the
> forward slash symbol "/". Valid example:
> /get/parameters2-/by1./path0_.

I get the same error if the prefixes end in "/". What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: What version of the AWS CLI are you using?  Can you run this command on the command line?

Comment: `aws --version == aws-cli/2.0.48 Python/3.7.7 Windows/10 exe/AMD64`, it's the latest version of the CLI tool.

Comment: Ah, it's an incompatibility with Gitbash, for some reason. Windows CMD works.

Comment: I just tried, and worked in my Mac too. Seems to have some problem with Gitbash.

Comment: Just for your note, it seems to be an older [bug](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=288723) which is fixed though.

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue with Gitbash still exists as the CLI is the very latest version which is available, I've just updated and it's still an issue.

Comment: What if you put the path in double quotes?

Comment: Single quotes, double quotes, no quotes - all give the same error.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using MSYS-based bash on Windows, make sure you prefix with
MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=*
to prevent it from expanding /prefix/prefix2 to a windows path.

Answer (score 4):

For windows Git Bash, You need to use MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="*" in Environemnt variable (like mentioned by @Dylan Nicholson), or just use export as below

The exact code needed is as below

```
export MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="*"
```

after that you can call the command normally as below

```
aws ssm describe-parameters --parameter-filters "Key=Name,Values=/dev/another/path"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Windows based command use:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path '//dev//another//path'
```

(Double slash)

That solved my issue on Windows.

Comment: Gitbash + Windows, double slashes did the trick; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing a beginning slash.

I had: `mydeployid/my/path/value`

And that gave me this error. The text in the error is misleading, I just had to change it to: `/mydeployid/my/path/value`